# Ошибка при построение столбчатой диаграммы в Python с использованием DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Необходимо построить график столбчатой диаграммы, в котором будет отображено каково соотношение погибших и выживших в зависимости от пола? Есть некоторый контейнер train_df, в котором находится много данных, в т.ч. пол (sex) - 'male', 'female' и факт выживания в авиакатастрофе (Survived) - bool. С помощью источника мне удалось сделать такой вот код, но он выдаёт ошибку

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Сколько источников посмотрел, не могу избавится от этой проблемы. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем заключается проблема?

```
labels = train_df['Survived']
mens = train_df[train_df['Sex'] == 'male']
womens = train_df[train_df['Sex'] == 'female']

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, mens, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, womens, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 0):

В новые датафреймы mens и womens вы переписываете строки из исходного датафрейма, удовлетворяющие условия. Причем в каждой строке новых датафреймов, очевидно, есть много параметров - как минимум, 'Sex' и 'Survived'.

Во-первых, при построении бар-графиков по датафреймам стоит использовать функцию DataFrame.plot.bar().

Во-вторых, в бар-графике библиотеки Matplotlib, которую вы используете, вторым параметром идет "scalar or sequence of scalars", т.е. конкретные числа, характеризующие объекты из первого параметра. А у вас там вообще какая-то каша.

Выберите один из вариантов и приведите данные к виду, которые требуют указанные функции.